# Docker Hot Reload not working in Angular Project on Windows PC with Laravel Backend

Tags: angular, docker, visual-studio-code

I just set-up my Angular project using a Docker container and the page doesn't reload on autosave.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-slim
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.2
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200
```

docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  angular-service:
    container_name: gamer-action-gg
    build: .
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
    command: >
      bash -c "npm install --quiet --no-progress && npm rebuild node-sass && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue could be releated to different sides, I hope that your is ones of the following:

1. There could be a wrong mapping on volume in Dockerfile:
   If the path of local machine is, for example, `myfolder/app` the Dockerfile volume path need to match with ones on local machine so in this case will be `myfolder/app`
2. In your package.json you need to pass a proxy ip that allow coummunication between localhost and the container, so you need to edit your package.json with the following inside scripts object:

`"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll"`

3. The ports between docker and local machine Need to be mapping to match each others, something like:

*Dockerfile* :

`EXPOSE 12345`

*docker-compose.yml* :

`port: 12345:12345`

Check this project that I pushed on GitHub that build an Angular app with Docker (I hope that It can be useful for Docker side) [angular app dockerized](https://github.com/SAGOlab/tax-sales-problem?files=1)

4. Check your *angular-cli.json*, at the end ("defaults" object section), you need to have a part similar to this:

```
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {},
    "serve": {
        "port": 4200,
        "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "poll": 1000
   }
```

Hope that one of this could help you.
Let me know.